# Как правильно выйти из бесконечного цикла

Tags: python, python-3.x, циклы, while, break

Столкнулся с проблемой в цикле.
Его нужно прервать по команде `"done:"`, но при этом, чтобы вызывалась ошибка "Invalid input" в блоке try / except. 
В моем же случае исключение ошибки ввода не позволяет прервать такой цикл строчкой.

````
largest = 0
smallest = 0
while True:
    try:
        num = int(input("Enter a number: "))
    except:
        print("Invalid input")
        continue
    if num == "done":
        break
    elif largest < num:
        largest = num
    elif smallest < num:
        smallest = num

print("Maximum is ", largest)
print("Minimum is ", smallest)```
````

Comment: уточните вопрос. У меня при вводе "done" он пишет "Invalid input". В чем проблема?

Comment: по задаче "done" должен цикл прерывать, после чего выводить ``` print("Maximum is ", largest)
print("Minimum is ", smallest)```ниже. А здесь код продолжает запрашивать ввод, break не срабатывает

Comment: ясно. Тогда ответьте себе (можете и мне) на несколько вопросов: 1) какой смысл в `continue` - что произойдет, как думаете? 2) вы про `try/except/finally` знаете? Не хотите с `finally` попробовать? 3) Как `num`, который `int` должен принять в себя `done`, чтобы `if num == "done"` сработал?

Comment: Винесіть ```input``` до початку ```try```, а всередині ```try``` робіть перетворення до типу ```int```. Тоді ще до початку ```try``` можна буде перевірити чи ```num == 'done'```.

Comment: да и ` elif smallest < num:` вызывает сомнения.

Comment: @Сергей Там напевно малося на увазі ```elif smallest > num:```

Comment: @VektorValentine, я знаю. Я просто предпочитаю, чтобы автор сам догадывался, что поменять надо, так ему полезнее. 2) Учтите, что мне (да и большинству), чтобы вас понимать, приходится в Google Translate постоянно лезть:-) Это киевляне вас поймут и так.

Comment: @VektorValentine, большое спасибо!

Comment: @Сергей Хорошая затея с "самопониманием". А по поводу языка - впредь постараюсь увеличить коефициент понимания и общаться на русском :-) (Хотя мой брат говорит другое).

Comment: @Сергей спасибо что указали на ошибки, я пайтон всего неделю изучаю и еще путаюсь в коде, так что любая инфа полезна

Comment: @VektorValentine, спасибо. А относительно брата - всё зависит от того, что в приоритете. Если хотеть иметь тут интернациональное сообщество, помогающее друг другу, то нужен язык, который все сразу понимают. Чисто практически:-)

Comment: Если честно, не очень понимаю, зачем `try` дергать. У Вас кроме строки из `input()` ничего не вылезет как ни старайтесь, почему бы не проверить на `isnumeric` введенное значение?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так

```
largest = 0
smallest = 0
fl = False

while True:
    try:
        _input = input("Enter a number: ")
        num = int(_input)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Invalid input: {e}")
        num = _input
        fl = True
        #print(f'num = {num}') #
#        continue
        
    if num == "done":
        break
    elif fl:
         fl = False
    elif largest < num:
        largest = num
    elif smallest < num:
        smallest = num

print("Maximum is ", largest)
print("Minimum is ", smallest)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю Вам так:

```py
largest = 0
smallest = 0
while True:
    try:
        answer = input("Enter a number: ")
        number = int(answer)
    except (TypeError, ValueError):
        if answer == "done":
            break
        else:
            print("Invalid input")
    else:
        if largest < number:
            largest = number
        elif number < smallest:
            smallest = number

print("Maximum is ", largest)
print("Minimum is ", smallest)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
values = {0}

while True:
    if (reply := input("Enter a number: ")) == 'done':
        break
    sign = ''
    if reply.startswith(('+', '-')):
        sign, *val = reply
        reply = ''.join(val)
    if not reply.isnumeric():
        print('Wrong value. Try once more.')
        continue

    values.add(
        int(sign + reply)
    )

print("Maximum is ", max(values))
print("Minimum is ", min(values))
```

---

*Если чем-то не устраивает использование `max` и `min`

можно так:*

```py
smallest = 0
largest = 0

while True:
    if (reply := input("Enter a number: ")) == 'done':
        break
    sign = ''
    if reply.startswith(('+', '-')):
        sign, *val = reply
        reply = ''.join(val)
    if not reply.isnumeric():
        print('Wrong value. Try once more.')
        continue

    smallest, _, largest = sorted([smallest, int(sign + reply), largest])

print("Maximum is ", smallest)
print("Minimum is ", largest)
```